# Creating an empty solution in an existing folder using VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

this is my first question at stackoverflow so please be gentle.

I have an existing folder called 'src' where I want to put my VS 2008 projects (BusinessLayer, BusinessLayer.Tests, etc...). Initially, I just want to put an empty solution file directly inside the 'src' folder. But creating an empty solution using VS 2008 always results to a new folder being created inside my 'src' folder. The solution file is located inside this new folder.

I can think of two possible workarounds. First I can move the solution file to my 'src' folder. Second, I can delete the new folder that was created by VS 2008 and save the solution. VS 2008 will then display a 'Save As' dialog where I can specify the location of the solution file.

So here are my questions:

Is there any setting in VS 2008 IDE that I can change so that it will create a new solution file directly into an specified folder (instead of creating a new folder and putting the solution file inside it)?

Creating an empty solution directly inside an existing folder is possible in VS 2003 (by unchecking the 'Create directory for solution' option). Do you know any reason why this feature has been removed from VS 2008?

Comment: If I create a new project I see the checkbox "Create directory for solution", so I don't see where is your problem.

Comment: The checkbox is disabled when you select 'Blank Solution' from the project templates, so you cannot uncheck it. Basically, I want to create a blank solution in an existing folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related: [create blank solution - can't uncheck "Create Directory for Solution"](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=106392)

How unfortunate.

I recommend you create the solution file in a dummy location (and then close that solution in VS), then move it manually to the folder where you really want it (and open it in VS again).